# Problem: Payment between smart contracts without reducing the balance of the sender contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, balances, solidity-0.5.x, transfer

I work on Truffle. I have two smart contracts `A` and `B`. Codes of them are same. `A` should transfer some ether to `B` and store some information about this payment. I funded `A` with `METAMASK`. But, whenever i try a transaction from `A` to `B` , with

`ax1.pay.sendTransaction('address of B',{value:'1000000000000000000', gasPrice:200})`

In Truffle console, there are two problems: 1- balance of `B` increases but balance of `A` does not decrease. 2- This transaction does not be recorded in the leger.

A:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
import "./B.sol";
contract A{

    event Payment(address recipient, uint value);
    event Receive(address sender, uint value);

    address sender;
    address payable receiver;
    uint sentValue;
    uint receiptValue;
    uint gasPrice;

    function pay(address payable recipient) external payable{\\Transfers some ether to B
        recipient.transfer(msg.value);
        B(recipient).cash(msg.value, tx.gasprice);
        receiver=recipient;
        sentValue=msg.value;
        gasPrice=tx.gasprice;
        emit Payment(recipient, msg.value);
    }

    function payView() public view returns(address, string memory, string memory, string memory){\\Shows some data about the last transfer.
        return (receiver, uint2str(sentValue), uint2str(gasPrice), uint2str(address(this).balance));
    }

    function cash(uint cashValue, uint GasPrice) external payable{\\Records some data about the last received transaction
        sender=msg.sender;
        receiptValue=cashValue;
        gasPrice=GasPrice;
        emit Receive(msg.sender, cashValue);
    }

    function cashView() public view returns(address, string memory, string memory, string memory){\\Shows some data about the last received transaction
        return (sender, uint2str(receiptValue), uint2str(gasPrice), uint2str(address(this).balance));
    }

    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory ) {
        if (_i == 0) {
                return "0";
         }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
                len++;
              j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len - 1;
        while (_i != 0) {
             bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
             _i /= 10;
         }
        return string(bstr);
    }

    function() external payable{}

}
```

B:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
import "./A.sol";
contract B{


    event Payment(address recipient, uint value);
    event Receive(address sender, uint value);

    address sender;
    address payable receiver;
    uint sentValue;
    uint receiptValue;
    uint gasPrice;

    function pay(address payable recipient) external payable{\\Transfers some ether to A
        recipient.transfer(msg.value);
        A(recipient).cash(msg.value, tx.gasprice);
        receiver=recipient;
        sentValue=msg.value;
        gasPrice=tx.gasprice;
        emit Payment(recipient, msg.value);
    }

    function payView() public view returns(address, string memory, string memory, string memory){\\Shows some data about the last transfer.
        return (receiver, uint2str(sentValue), uint2str(gasPrice), uint2str(address(this).balance));
    }

    function cash(uint cashValue, uint GasPrice) external payable{\\Records some data about the last received transaction
        sender=msg.sender;
        receiptValue=cashValue;
        gasPrice=GasPrice;
        emit Receive(msg.sender, cashValue);
    }

    function cashView() public view returns(address, string memory, string memory, string memory){\\Shows some data about the last received transaction
        return (sender, uint2str(receiptValue), uint2str(gasPrice), uint2str(address(this).balance));
    }

    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory ) {
        if (_i == 0) {
                return "0";
         }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
                len++;
              j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len - 1;
        while (_i != 0) {
             bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
             _i /= 10;
         }
        return string(bstr);
    }
    function() external payable{}
}
```

Define `A` and `B` after deployment and funding `A`with `METAMASK`:
[image]

After that, when i transferred ether to `B` ,with `pay()` function in `A`,  i tried to see the result with `payView()` in `A` and `cashView()` in `B`:
[image]

As you can see the balance of `A` didn't decrease. This transaction was recorded in block 68 but when i see the block, it says a transaction occured between my wallet and `A` not between `A` and `B`:
[image]

What are the reasons for these two things? How can i see the transaction in the ledger and the decreased balance on that.

Comment: You should accept answers to previous questions of yours if you're expecting help in future questions!

Comment: @goodvibration: I'm sorry. I had forgotten to mark your last answer to me. i did it. You are the one who has always helped me in this forum. I hope I didn't offend you.

Comment: There is not a single transaction in the code that you've posted in those two screenshots (and BTW, please post them as plain text (formatted as code), so that people here will be able to refer to that information). You should show in code how you "transferred ether to B ,with pay()".

Comment: @goodvibration: I transferred ether to `B` with `ax1.pay.sendTransaction('address of B',{value:'1000000000000000000', gasPrice:200})` in Truffle console.

Comment: This transaction is executed via the account specified in the `from` field in the `options` object that you pass to `sendTransaction`. Since you haven't specified this field, I would guess that it takes `accounts[0]` by default. You can verify this by looking into the balance of that account and see that it has decreased by how much you've expected the balance of contract `A` to decrease.

Comment: @goodvibration: This is right. Balance of `accounts[0]` will be decreaesd. But, when i set address of `A` as `from` just like `ax1.pay.sendTransaction('Address of B',{ value:'1000000000000000000', gasPrice:200, from: 'Address of A'})` this error occurs: `Error: Returned error: sender account not recognized`. what is this and how can i solve it?

Comment: You cannot use this address as `from`, because unlike your `accounts`, it is not unlocked on the node that you're connected to. Worse than that - you don't even have the private key of that address. You cannot just send Ether from a contract. Think how bad that would be for the entire eco-system if something like that was possible. You need to implement a function in that contract to do the ether sending, and then call that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: 
In order to send some ether to `B` from the balance of `A`, using `ax1.pay.sendTransaction('address of B',{value:'1000000000000000000', gasPrice:200}` is inappropriate. Whenever, we use `{from:'...', value:'...' , gasPrice:..., gas:...}` in  `.sendTransaction(...)`, in fact, we are telling to `A` "decrease as much as is determined in `value:'...'` from balance of the account corresponds to`from:'...'` and add it to the balance of `B`" . If `from:'...'` is not determined the `accounts[0]` in Ganache will be considered. But, if we want to decrease the balance of `A` as much as `value:'...'` and add it to the balance of `B`, should modify `pay()` function in `A` and method of transaction sending in Truffle console. For that, we add an other parameter to `pay()` and set it as argument of `.transfer()`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
import "./B.sol";
contract A

.
.
.

  function pay(address payable recipient, uint val) external payable{
        recipient.transfer(val);
        A(recipient).cash(val, tx.gasprice);
        receiver=recipient;
        sentValue=val;
        gasPrice=tx.gasprice;
        emit Payment(recipient, val);
    }

.
.
.

}
```

And in Truffle console:

`ax1.pay.sendTransaction('address of B', '100000000000000',{gasPrice:200})`

Now, one can see that the balance of `A` will be decreased as much as determined with `val`. But, it must be noted that by this way `val` can not be more than `999999999999999 wei`

Problem 2:

In Truffle, just the interaction between a wallet account and a contract account is recorded in the ledger.

I hope this answer can help.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a command in a form like:

```
ax1.pay.sendTransaction(<address>,{from:<address>, value:<value>, gas:<...>, gasPrice:<...>})
```

you should define the sender's address in field `from:` , otherwise, `accounts[0]` in Ganache accounts will be considered as the sender and its balance will be decreased. Now, if your sender is a contract you can't use this command by this form. Because, the address is embedded in field `from:` must be of Ganache while contract account is not of that. According to your purpose, i suggest to embed the sender's value in contract's function `.pay(...)` as an argument. Moreover, Truffle never records an interaction between two contracts.